# Bing maps V8 image conversion error "Tainted canvases may not be exported"

Tags: jquery, .net, html5-canvas, bing-maps

I have BingMaps V8 in my solution, I'm converting the BingMaps layers (canvas) to image and rendering it into PDF. It was working fine when I was developing the application, now it started showing error "Tainted canvases may not be exported." Please help me to resolve the issue.

[Look at the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVQAw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicates that something in one of the images in the canvas is either not on the same domain as the website or does not have CORs enabled. Take a look at the different datasets you are adding to the map and try removing each one until the error goes away. This should help you identify where the issue is.

Comment: tried with all possible ways, finally got to know microsoft have kept CORS access restriction to manipulate the imagery canvas. Bing maps V8 release notes says, we can export map canvas as image but there are no predefined functions available for this.

Comment: The release notes don't say anything about exporting the canvas: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt770019.aspx There were plans to add support for this and it was mentioned as a planned feature during the launch of V8 last year and was mentioned in a blog post. However, it was found that there are too many browser differences to make this a fully functionality feature. As such this feature was cut.